# Get result based on multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, select, conditional-statements

My head is stuck on this. I want the following:

I would like to find the nr number which matches both criteria:
(title='T2' AND val >=2) and (title='T3' AND val>=4)

So the result would be 3 in this case:

```
| nr    | title   | val       |
|:------|--------:|:---------:|
| 1     |      T1 |    1     
| 1     |      T2 |    5
| 1     |      T3 |    3
| 3     |      T1 |    2
| 3     |      T2 |    2
| 3     |      T3 |    4
```

As you see, only nr = 3 matches both criteria.
How would I write a query to return nr = 3?

This of course is not working

```
SELECT DISTINCT nr FROM table WHERE title = 'T2' AND val >= 2 AND title = 'T3' AND val >= 4
```

Shouldn't be that hard, right? I once did something similar joining the table on its self...

Comment: Title can't be T2 and T3 *at the same time.*  You probably mean OR, not AND.  Your problem is that your requirements aren't clear; you're basically stating SQL in your question that won't work.

Comment: Thats my problem. I mean AND.

Comment: Then I don't know how you get 3 out of that.  The description you've provided will return a set with no records.

Comment: because two rows (nr 3) match the criteria

Comment: Your criteria is specifying `value` >=2, not `nr`.  Like I said, your requirements are unclear.  You need to be much more specific than this.  For example: `WHERE title = "T1" AND nr = 3 ...`

Comment: is this what you mean `(title = 'T2' AND value >= 2) AND (title = 'T3' AND value >=4)`?? This boolean will always return false.

Comment: thats right. like i said i want the number where all rows match the criteria. should be simple to understand.

Comment: That's not specific enough.  You have to specify *which column  you want to compare with which value.*  SQL demands this level of specificity.

Comment: ... reminding me of that joke where new father asks the doctor `is it a boy or a girl` and the doctor replies `yes`.

Comment: well i can't be more specific. nr 1 does not match because val of T3 is not >= 4. so only nr 3 matches.

Comment: i'm shure someone can understand and solve this.

Comment: @Mike, the edit you made (sql you tried) exactly reflects the condition you stated earlier in the question `T2 and value is >= 2 AND title is T3 and value is >= 4`. I think the SO community is trying to tell you this sentence will logically NEVER return any rows, and asking for clarification.

Comment: You don't want `title = 'T2' AND val >= 2 AND title = 'T3' AND val >= 4`, but `title = 'T2' AND val >= 2 OR title = 'T3' AND val >= 4` never heard about the difference between `AND` and `OR` ??? !!!

Comment: first try to understand the question...or look below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT nr 
FROM table 
WHERE (title = 'T2' AND val >= 2) OR 
      (title = 'T3' AND val >= 4) 
GROUP BY nr 
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The query you are asking for is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nr FROM tbl WHERE title='T2' AND val >=2
AND nr IN
(
SELECT nr FROM tbl WHERE title='T3' AND val>=4
)
```

Where tbl is the table you are searching
which results in 3.
This is because 3 meets both conditions.

If you wish to add more criteria just do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nr FROM tbl WHERE title='T2' AND val >=2
AND nr IN
(
SELECT nr FROM tbl WHERE title='T3' AND val>=4
)
AND nr IN (SELECT nr FROM tbl WHERE {new_criteria_1})
AND nr IN (SELECT nr FROM tbl WHERE {new_criteria_2})
AND nr IN (SELECT nr FROM tbl WHERE {new_criteria_3})
Where {new_criteria_1,2,3....n} are the new criteria in the WHERE clause you want to match.
```

Comment: That's exactly what i was asking for. Thanks. Is there a way this query can be extended for more than two criteria?

Comment: Yes, you can add multiple criteria. Just add another AND nr IN
(
SELECT nr FROM tbl WHERE {new_criteria}
)

Comment: Yes, I reworded your question as I could see what you were asking for but I could understand why people struggled with understanding it.